# iOS Store Review Guidelines : Can I use iTunes Search API on my app?

Tags: ios

My app which uses "iTunes Search API" has rejected because of violation of the review guidelines (12.1). I would like to know whether "iTunes Search API" is unavailable to use in iOS apps or not.

If some apps which use the API have approved, I will try to re-apply it. Any help will be appreciated.

Apple's approval guidelines is this.

> 12.1 Applications that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple
>   Developer Programs, etc) or create rankings using content from Apple
>   sites and services will be rejected
>        https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#scraping-aggregation

Comment: Most Apps use a server (Not Apple's) which compiles data in the App Store and then makes the rankings. I am not sure though...

Comment: @iProgrammed Thanks. it's very helpful comment! I will ask apple whether the way is available or not.

Comment: @yusaku If the api is available then I don't think that they will reject the app.

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore Thank you. I'm encouraged by your hopeful comment!

Comment: @zono Did apple respond? If yes, what did they say?

Comment: @Lukas Hi, No response so far.

Comment: What did they say?

Comment: Hi @zono, I see this question is very old at this point, but I have the same question as you did and wondering how things panned out. Were you able to use iTunes search results in your app?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be part of the iTunes affiliate program to use the previews. 
The first sentence of the "Legal" section of the Search API reads:

> Affiliate may use certain promotional content as may be provided by Apple, including previews of songs and music videos, album art, and App icons

And from the Affiliate Program's page:

> Affiliate Tools: A variety of advanced tools are available to help technically savvy partners create links to iTunes, App Store and Mac App Store. These include a Search API, an Enterprise Partner Feed that provides advanced data feed for the whole store and a Web iMix tool that can be used to create a dynamic playlist.

It remains unclear... but I wouldn't take any chances, join the affiliates! Plus you can profit share if your app leads to a purchase.
[Apple Affiliate Program](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/app-store-affiliate-program.html)

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from the legal section of iTunes API Page:

> Developers may use certain promotional content as may be provided by Apple, including previews of songs and music videos, album art, and App icons ("Promo Content"), for the purposes of promoting the subject of the Promo Content; provided such Promo Content: (i) is placed only on pages that promote the content on which the Promo Content is based; (ii) is proximate to a "Download on iTunes", "Download on App Store" or "Download on iBooks Store" badge (as approved by Apple) that acts as a link directly to pages within iTunes or the App Store where consumers can purchase the promoted content; (iii) includes attribution indicating the Promo Content was "provided courtesy of iTunes" if such Promo Content includes song or music video previews; (iv) is streamed only, and not downloaded, saved, cached, or synchronized with video, if such Promo Content includes song or music video previews; (v) is not used for independent entertainment value apart from its promotional purpose; and (vi) is not used to promote any other goods or services. Developer acknowledges that Apple provides the Promo Content "as is," and disclaims any and all representations or warranties, including, but not limited to, non-infringement. Developer shall forward any claims received in connection with the Promo Content to Apple immediately upon receipt, and will remove any Promo Content immediately upon request from Apple.